# How to restore integers from my json.dumps file (for display in my javascript chart) when using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, pie-chart

In my Django application, I have a very basic pie chart model with the name column as a CharField and the stats column as an IntegerField. I also have some JavaScript code on my html page that displays a pie chart -- but I'm only able to get it working if I hardcode the values as an array. I was hoping to instead display the data from my model/ DB as `{{ values|safe }}` in pie chart form, pulling the values from json dumps of my DB data.

Here's what I've tried, as seen in my **views.py** file:

```
def metrics(request):
    pietitle = serializers.serialize('json', PieChart.objects.all(),fields=('title'))
    piestats = serializers.serialize('json', PieChart.objects.all(),fields=('stats'))
    piedata=[[pietitle, piestats]]
    json_data = json.dumps(piedata) 
    data_json= json.loads(json_data)
    return render(request, "metrics.html", {"values": data_json})
```

On my HTML page, the message I'm getting is simply "No Data", and I'm fairly certain that's because when I serialize the stats field, it's converted to a string and is unable to be interpreted as integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the data is in the correct format for the pie chart.

With this line `piedata=[[pietitle, piestats]]`, if you wanted to access the first title you'd have to go `data_json[0][0][0]` and for the first lot of stats you'll have to go `data_json[0][1][0]`

Edit answer based on comment:

```
piedata = []

for i in range(len(pietitle)):
    piedata.append([pietitle[i], piestats[I]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I will think this through and see if it may resolve the issue... 
The format it's supposed to be in is as follows: [ ['name', integer], ['name', integer], ['name', integer] ]

Comment: Updated answer for how you can make create this format